# installing with bower on heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, bower

I am working with heroku and flask. I am trying to use multibuild pack on heroku to build my dependencies. I came across [this repo](https://github.com/ejholmes/heroku-buildpack-bower) and followed the instructions.

First, I set my `BUILDPACK_URL` and checked it

```
=== corvid Config Vars
BUILDPACK_URL:               https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi.git
```

.buildpacks file:

```
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs
https://github.com/ejholmes/heroku-buildpack-bower
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python
```

My `package.json` looks as follows:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "bower": "latest"
  }
}
```

I deploy my project to heroku, but end up getting the following error whenever it tries to deploy.

```
=====> Downloading Buildpack: https://github.com/ejholmes/heroku-buildpack-bower
=====> Detected Framework: Bower buildpack

module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'bower-logger'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/tmp/build_4a6d8bfa-5458-4908-95bc-e6f3af6d5b2a/node_modules/bower/bin/bower:8:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Multipack app
```

What is the problem here?

Full project files can be found [here](https://github.com/DarkCrowz/corvid_site)

Comment: I've never used bower, so I have no idea why something is trying to use bower-logger (perhaps something heroku itself is trying to use?), but have you tried adding bower-logger as a dependency in your `package.json` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not much of an answer, sorry for that, but too much for a comment...

When I do:

1. git clone https://github.com/DarkCrowz/corvid_site.git
2. cd corvid_site
3. heroku create
4. heroku config:set BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi
5. git push heroku master

It looks like it gets deployed fine, at least the bower buildpack completed and did install bower-logger.
bower-logger is required by bower. Do you see it in the deployed site?

`heroku run "ls node_modules/bower/node_modules"`

Comment: well that's a little unusual... I deleted my project, pulled from origin master, then restarted and everything installed fine